# What does 会 mean in 为什么我会觉得历史课很无聊？

Tags: meaning-in-context

“为什么我((会))觉得历史课很无聊？”. The translation of the sentence is "Why do I think history lessons are boring?". I don't get why 会 is used since 会 means "to be able to" or is used to indicate future tense.

Comment: bkrs：会 I(12) 应当; 应须 [should; ought to]。 如: 会须(当须, 应当); 会应(该当)
III
(1) 必然, 一定 [certainly; definitely]
吾已失恩义, 会不相从许。 --古乐府《孔雀东南飞》
长风破浪会有时。 --唐·李白《行路难》
(2) 恰巧, 正好 [just; right; happen to]
会天大雨。 --《史记·陈涉世家》
会其怒。 --《史记·项羽本纪》
会幸苑中。 --宋·王谠《唐语林·雅量》
会雨大作, 因留寺。 --《徐霞客游记·游黄山记》
会宾客大宴。 --《虞初新志·秋声诗自序》
will
to be likely to
to be sure to

Comment: according to "会：be likely to, could，ought to be": possibly ："Why do I think history lessons could be，are likely,ought to be boring?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

会 has many meanings

in this context, "会" functions as  "would"

> [Would](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would): modal verb (INTENTION/ POSSIBILITY)
>
> "为什么我(会)觉得历史课很无聊?" = "why (would) I think history class is boring?"
>
> *If there's no explanation following the question,  it is a rhetorical question*

Example of 'would' as a modal verb :

"If it doesn't rain, I would go"  (INTENTION)

"One of them would die if they fight each other" (POSSIBILITY)

Answer (score 0):

"为什么我(会)觉得历史课很无聊?"

If this is not a question but a mere statement of fact, then the (会) is unnecessary, giving us -- 我觉得历史课很无聊

But because it is a question, the 会 is to solicit a reason from anyone answering why you "would (会) think or feel, (觉得), history lessons are boring"

Answer (score 0):

It does not really have any special connotation in this case.

With or without it, the meaning of the sentence is identical. Its use only makes the sentence less formal.

It is mostly used in informal situations (e.g. everyday dialogues) and is not used in formal presentations.